# Fetch Google plus news feed in native ios

Tags: ios, social-networking

i am working on ios app, and i want to fetch Google Plus news feed like friend list, user detail, in my ios app.
in facebook its possible to fetch the active user's profile feed, but for google pluse i didnot found any thing to show user feed.

if any one know how to do this for iphone application then please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After you have signed in a user with Google, you can access the user's age range, language, public profile information, and people that they have circled.

If you request the [plus.profile.emails.read scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes), you can also get their email address. With this rich social data, you can build engaging experiences and an instant community in your app.

For example, you might connect your user with their friends that also use your app or you might make suggestions based on their friends' activities within your app.

Please look at [Getting people and profile information](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people)

Comment: Thanks for the details,I am getting this details but i want to fetch **news feed** (like facebook news feed)

Comment: Please check https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities
it may help you